# How to create a GitHub Actions workflow such that it always fail until a PR is approved?

Tags: github, github-actions

Basically my workflow should trigger whenever there is an activity to PR branch and must fail until PR is approved.

To give more context below is my CI pipeline:

workflow 1 -> workflow 2-> workflow 3

- workflow 1: Triggered when there is any pull request and uses madrapps/add-reviewers@v1 action to trigger automatic assignment of reviewers. If there is a new push to PR branch re-review is requested.
- workflow 2 : Which is based on this question. This will sort of act like gate for workflow 3. This has to be triggered for every activity in PR branch and must fail if no approval is given.
- workflow 3: This will do final build checks, formatting and auto merging PR requests. But this workflow is triggered only after workflow 2 is completed successfully.

Please find my implementation of  workflow 2 below.

```yml
 name: Review_submitted_check



on:
  pull_request:
    types: 
    branches:
      - test_pr
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
    branches: test_pr
    
  

jobs:   
  approval:
    
    runs-on: ros-runner
    steps:
      - name: verify pass
        if: github.event.review.state == 'approved'
        run: exit 0
      - name: verify fail
        if: github.event.review.state != 'approved'
        run: exit 1
```

The problem is two jobs are run for different trigger. One for approval submission and other for all PR activity. Since at a time only one of the job will succeed, I will always have one failed job.

[image]

Please advise on a better approach to this problem.

Comment: What's the point of workflow 2, why doesn't workflow 3 just check if the PR is approved then bail out otherwise?

Comment: I want to have a fail indicator displayed until approval comes in.

Comment: And the failing workflow 3 wouldn't indicate that because...?

Comment: How do I fail it ? I use a if statement to check if approval has come in . If approval comes it executes a job with <name1>. Assuming that I create another job<name2> within workflow 3 to create the fail condition wouldn't cause the same issue as I said before (2 jobs of same workflow one fails and other succeeds)?

Comment: Why wouldn't it just be triggered on review, though? Do you need a failing workflow to tell you you can't merge a PR because it's not approved when: 1. you can't merge it, because... it's not approved; and 2. you don't merge anyway because the workflow does that for you on approval? There doesn't seem to be any value to that.

Comment: I was able to implement that using below github actions: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/required-review